# Does remotely wiping my mac os remotely also erase data on a Windows partition?

Tags: windows, windows-10, macos, mac, boot-camp

I am running Mac (big sur) with Windows installed via bootcamp on another partition. If my device is stolen I will need to ensure all the data in my windows partition also gets wiped along with the data on mac os (Even if the thief opens the windows partition first). I was wondering whether 'Find my device' will do this or whether I need to install some software on Windows to enable me to wipe it remotely such as Microsoft InTune or similar.

My concern is the code that listens for wipe notifications from the find my device service only runs on mac os and so won't run if booted into windows. I am also assuming since there is no internet connection before an os is booted it won't be able to receive that notification. Perhaps the bootcamp assistant program installed on Windows does this for me?

Comment: All of the info on Apple.com and other news/help sites say the same thing, using "Find My" you can "erase your device." The problem here is that nowhere do they say what that means. Erase just your profile? Erase just personal data? Erase the macOS (data) partition? Erase (reformat?) the whole drive? I would think that your Mac needs to be booted into macOS for this to work, but that is also unclear.

Comment: Maybe I should find a place where I can direct this question to apple? It is a highly technical question though so I don't think it would be easy for them to know as well... it is not your classic 'How do I update my iPad' kinda question :P  But could be worth a shot

Comment: I also realize that I have Boot camp installed on my windows and I wonder if that can communicate with find my device? Potentially if I can find my device when I am running windows it is safe to assume it can erase the whole drive as well? Unfortunately I cannot test the erase part of this on my machine even if it can connect

Comment: If you still have an active AppleCare warranty on any Mac you can ask that question of Apple Support for free. Otherwise it will cost you. But give it a couple of days here, maybe someone knows or can link to an official Apple pronouncement on the matter. As for Windows installed on your Mac, I don't know if Find My is a part of Boot Camp. It would make sense that it is but that would be me guessing...